# Magento2: Cron is not working. All status are pending in database

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, magento-cron

I have set the cron on my server. In cron log file message update successfully "Ran jobs by schedule". But in the database, all cron is showing status pending.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento_main/bin/magento cron:run  >> /var/www/html/magento_main/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini[your php.ini] /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run > /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log&

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini[your php.ini path] /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php > /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log&

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini[your php.ini path] /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run > /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

Instead of

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento_main/bin/magento cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento_main/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Make sure you set up cron properly in your server.

you can check by here [https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html]

For set up get a reference from here [https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-cron-job/]

also, make sure you have single/multiple PHP version, if you have multiple PHP version then you need to set proper PHP library like

> /usr/bin/php7.1 bin/magento

Comment: I have set the cron. No errors in the cron log file . Got the message in log file  "Ran jobs by schedule". But cron is not working. status are pending in database.

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to check cron settings at server @Masud Shaikh